# Integrate $\int^\infty_0 \dfrac{\sin x}{x^3}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, even-and-odd-functions

By using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395247/contour-method-to-show-that-int-0-infty-fracx-sin-xx3-dx-frac-pi4) method we can evaluate $\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\,dz=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and I intended to solve $\displaystyle\int^\infty_0 \dfrac{\sin x}{x^3}\,dx=\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\dfrac{1}{x^2}\,dx-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. But how can I integrate $\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\dfrac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ when [the integral does not converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+1%2Fx%5E2+from+0+to+inf)?

Comment: $\int^\infty_0 \dfrac{\sin x}{x^3}\,dx$ does not exist.

Comment: My Sage agrees with Kavi - "Integral is divergent."

Comment: Does that mean $\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\dfrac{a\sin x}{x^3}\,dx$ is also divergent for any complex number $a$?

Comment: For $\ x\ge0\ $,
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x^3}\ge\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{2x}\  ,
$$
so
$$
\int_b^c\frac{\sin x}{x^3}\,dx\ge\int_b^c\left(\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{2x}\right)\,dx\ .
$$
for $\ 0\le b\le c\ $.  What happens to the integral on the right of this inequality as $\ b\rightarrow0^+\ $?  What happens to the one on the left of the inequality if you multiply it by a complex number $\ a\ $ and take its limit as $\ b\rightarrow0^+\ $?

Comment: $x^{-3} \sin x \sim x^{-2}$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @Alvin You can factor out $a$ into the front of the integral and you are left with the case $a=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You must keep in mind that an equality like
$$
\int_A (f(x)+g(x))\,dx = \int_A f(x)\, dx + \int_A g(x)\,dx
$$

only holds if all three integrals exist. In your example, as it was pointed out in the comments, this is not the case.